# Creating a table in mydatabase from the results of querying the information schema

Tags: mysql

Let me clarify, that I am a newbie in mysql. I am trying to do something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table as (SELECT * FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydatabase'
        AND table_type = 'base table');
```

Then when I check `mydatabase`, `my_table` is not there. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Given a table named `table1` which contain two fields:

- `id`
- `querytoexecute`

You can populate `querytoexecute` with SQL requests.
See the example below containing two records creating two tables `my_table1` and `my_table2`.

```
 ___________________________________________________
|ID  |  querytoexecute                              |
|1   |  CREATE TABLE my_table1 (ID int, Name TEXT); |
|2   |  CREATE TABLE my_table2 (ID int, Name TEXT); |
 ___________________________________________________|
```

Then select the record to execute with the following query:

```
set @queryfromtable:= (select querytoexecute from table1 where id = 1);
PREPARE stmt FROM @queryfromtable;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: If it's not useful, just delete it then?

Comment: this is answer for above question, if you select information from schema database then you can create any table. why you think it is not useful? i can delete but i think many people can find very useful this sample!

Comment: Your edit said you are clearing the answer because it wasnt useful and i had to review your edit? I dont wanna delete it.. I just rejected the edit lol

Comment: sorry, as far as I can see there is no delete button for an answer

Comment: alex did my answer helped you?

Comment: thanks, nha i think this answer is useful and you improved it!